# Georeferencing and image in leaflet using react

Tags: reactjs, image-processing, leaflet, geospatial

im just throwing this into to ether and hoping someone has any good ideas.

The problem im trying to solve is;
Given the image of a mall.
Then i want to be able to perfectly overlay the image where the mall is located on my leaflet map withouth exiting my react app. (if that makes sense)

Issues that "will" arise, is that the images may be rotated, not big enough etc.
I have looked at the feature which QGIS has, where one can click on the map, then on the image (twice). And based on that, the image perfectly fits the map.

I am stuck on how to replicate the feature where clicking on the image and the map, should somehow give me the values needed to place the image perfectly over. So maybe its more so i am lacking the alogrithm to be able to compute the needed values.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you would be interested in [Leaflet.ImageOverlay.Rotated](https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.ImageOverlay.Rotated) plugin:

> Display rotated and skewed images in your LeafletJS maps.

Interactive demo: http://ivansanchez.github.io/Leaflet.ImageOverlay.Rotated/demo.html

Comment: Hmm this is not what i needs as i also want to georefrencs svg's